# Join Extension Method

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

I am having trouble figuring out how to do a simple left join using linq in an extension method.

I need to use an extension method as opposed to a comprehension query as I am paging the results.

```
var carParkPagedList =
db.CarPark
.Join(db.UserProfiles, cp => cp.UserProfileId, up => up.UserId, (cp, up))
.OrderBy(f => f.Name)
.Where(f => f.FloorId == floorId)
.Select(f => new CarParkListDisplayModel
{
    CarParkId = f.CarParkId,
    Name = f.Name
}).ToPagedList(page, 10);
```

I cannot find help on this anywhere, I have tried 101 linq examples and this is find for comprehension queries but won't provide any support for extension methods.

Comment: FYI: There's nothing stopping you from wrapping the query in parenthesis and calling a method on that (e.g: `(from x in y join blah..).CallMethodHere();`. I hate method syntax and joins.. just so unnatural.

Comment: this question lacks a lot of info.

Answer (score 1):

Ok thanks Simon, that approach worked and I will use that from now on, much more logical.

```
var carParkPagedList =
(from cp in db.CarPark
where cp.FloorId == floorId
join occupant in db.UserProfiles on cp.UserProfileId equals occupant.UserId into gj
from occupant in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
orderby cp.Name
select new CarParkListDisplayModel
{
    CarParkId = cp.CarParkId,
    Name = cp.Name,
    UsersName = (occupant == null ? "Un-ocupied" : occupant.FirstName + " " + occupant.LastName)
}).ToPagedList(page, 10);
```

Comment: REMEMBER that all the `query expression` will be translated into `method query`. You can do everything with `method query`, which sometimes `query expression` CAN'T do.